# index a Python Pandas dataframe with multiple conditions SQL like where statement

Tags: python, sql, indexing, pandas

I am experienced in R and new to Python Pandas.  I am trying to index a DataFrame to retrieve rows that meet a set of several logical conditions - much like the "where" statement of SQL.

I know how to do this in R with dataframes (and with R's data.table package,  which is more like a Pandas DataFrame than R's native dataframe).

Here's some sample code that constructs a DataFrame and a description of how I would like to index it.  Is there an easy way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate some data
mult = 10000
fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Kiwi', 'Grape', 'Orange', 'Strawberry']*mult
vegetables = ['Asparagus', 'Broccoli', 'Carrot', 'Lettuce', 'Rutabaga', 'Spinach']*mult
animals = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Fish', 'Lion', 'Mouse']*mult
xValues = np.random.normal(loc=80, scale=2, size=6*mult)
yValues = np.random.normal(loc=79, scale=2, size=6*mult)

data = {'Fruit': fruits,
        'Vegetable': vegetables, 
        'Animal': animals, 
        'xValue': xValues,
        'yValue': yValues,}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# shuffle the columns to break structure of repeating fruits, vegetables, animals
np.random.shuffle(df.Fruit)
np.random.shuffle(df.Vegetable)
np.random.shuffle(df.Animal)

df.head(30)

# filter sets
fruitsInclude = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Grape']
vegetablesExclude = ['Asparagus', 'Broccoli']

# subset1:  All rows and columns where:
#   (fruit in fruitsInclude) AND (Vegetable not in vegetablesExlude)

# subset2:  All rows and columns where:
#   (fruit in fruitsInclude) AND [(Vegetable not in vegetablesExlude) OR (Animal == 'Dog')]

# subset3:  All rows and specific columns where above logical conditions are true.
```

All help and inputs welcomed and highly appreciated!

Thanks,
Randall

Comment: Wow. Exactly what I needed.  Thanks for a quick and direct answer. Note that I spelled vegetablesExlude wrong... should have been   vegetablesExclude (with the c).  Corrected it in the code above so is should be copy and paste to test.  Thanks again.  Randall.

Answer (score 15):

```
# subset1:  All rows and columns where:
#   (fruit in fruitsInclude) AND (Vegetable not in vegetablesExlude)
df.ix[df['Fruit'].isin(fruitsInclude) & ~df['Vegetable'].isin(vegetablesExclude)]

# subset2:  All rows and columns where:
#   (fruit in fruitsInclude) AND [(Vegetable not in vegetablesExlude) OR (Animal == 'Dog')]
df.ix[df['Fruit'].isin(fruitsInclude) & (~df['Vegetable'].isin(vegetablesExclude) | (df['Animal']=='Dog'))]

# subset3:  All rows and specific columns where above logical conditions are true.
df.ix[df['Fruit'].isin(fruitsInclude) & ~df['Vegetable'].isin(vegetablesExclude) & (df['Animal']=='Dog')]
```

Comment: Barely beat me too it! That was the exact same solution I came up with +1

Comment: If all I wanted was the indexes, is there a shorter way than this: `df.ix[df['Fruit'].isin(fruitsInclude).index`

Comment: @Zhubarb: `df.index[df['Fruit'].isin(fruitsInclude)]` is shorter and (on my machine ~33%) faster than `df.ix[df['Fruit'].isin(fruitsInclude)].index`.