Looping over Pandas columns while counting rows that contain two specified values
I am trying to count each row in Pandas dataframe that contain two specified values, but the problem is that the values can be in any column. How can I loop the part with;
for col in con.columns:
    counts += len(con[(con[col]==name1)])

...so that I have two conditions, that require name1 and name2 to exist on the same row? I would use the cross tabulation, but the dataset is way too large for that.
con = pd.read_csv("keyword connections.txt", sep="\t")
key = pd.read_csv("keyword short list.txt", sep="\t")    
text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
    
i = 0
j = 0
k = 0
for i in range(0,key.size):
    name1 = key.iloc[i]["Keyword"]
    for j in range(0,key.size):
        name2 = key.iloc[j]["Keyword"]
        counts = 0
        for col in con.columns:
            counts += len(con[(con[col]==name1)])
        text_file.write(name1+"\t"+name2+"\t"+str(counts)+"\n")
        j += 1
        k += 1
    i += 1
text_file.close()
print(k)


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664913/how-to-print-rows-if-values-appear-in-any-column-of-pandas-dataframe

Assuming this example:
    col1   col2   col3
0  name1  other  name2
1  other  name2  other
2  name2  name1  other
3  other  other  other

You could use several masks built with eq and any and combine them with & to perform boolean indexing:
m1 = df.eq('name1').any(axis=1)
m2 = df.eq('name2').any(axis=1)

out = df[m1 & m2]

Or, from a list of values:
names = ['name1', 'name2']

out = df[np.logical_and.reduce([df.eq(n).any(axis=1)
                                for n in names])]

Alternatively, you could use a set of the wanted values and agg:
S = {'name1', 'name2'}

out = df[df.agg(S.issubset, axis=1)]

Output:
    col1   col2   col3
0  name1  other  name2
2  name2  name1  other

Intermediates:
    col1   col2   col3     m1     m2  m1&m2                 as_set  S.issubset
0  name1  other  name2   True   True   True  {name1, other, name2}        True
1  other  name2  other  False   True  False         {other, name2}       False
2  name2  name1  other   True   True   True  {name1, other, name2}        True
3  other  other  other  False  False  False                {other}       False

