# How to generate a boolean "indicator Series" based on inclusion in a set?

Tags: pandas

Here's the set-up for a toy example:

```
data = [['a',  1],
        ['b',  2],
        ['a',  3],
        ['b',  1],
        ['c',  2],
        ['c',  3],
        ['b',  1]]

colnames = tuple('XY')

df = pd.DataFrame(co.OrderedDict([(colnames[i],
                                   [row[i] for row in data])
                                  for i in range(len(colnames))]))
```

OK, to get a boolean indicator `Series` object (suitable for indexing) corresponding to whether the value in the `X` column is equal to `'a'` or not, I can do this:

```
In [230]: df['X'] == 'a'
Out[230]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
Name: X, dtype: bool
```

Fine, but what I really want to do is to test whether the value is *one of several possible* values.  I tried to use `set` inclusion for this, but it bombs:

```
In [231]: df['X'] in set(['a', 'b'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-266-0819ab764ce2> in <module>()
----> 1 df['X'] in set(['a', 'b'])

/Users/yt/.virtualenvs/pd/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in __hash__(self)
    639     def __hash__(self):
    640         raise TypeError('{0!r} objects are mutable, thus they cannot be'
--> 641                         ' hashed'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
    642
    643     def __iter__(self):

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

How can I achieve this?

Note: for the situation I'm working with, the set of allowable values is large, and known only at run time, so an `or` expression is out of the question.

Comment: Are you just looking for `isin`, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe)?

Comment: @DSM: bingo, that was exactly it.  I suppose this question is a duplicate...  I'll delete it if so.  If not, please post your comment as an answer so that I can give its due.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396898/index-a-python-pandas-dataframe-with-multiple-conditions-sql-like-where-statemen